# AngularJs service methods to accept object OR multiple parameters - Which one is best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

What is the best practice while creating Angular JS service methods. To accept multiple parameters or as a object.

```
var getMessages = function (appid, userId,limit) {
    var data = {
        "appid": appid,
        "userId": userId,
        "limit": limit,
    }
    // Call rest api using data variable
}
```

OR

```
var getMessages = function (data) {
// Call rest api using data variable
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best practice ever....

```
var getMessages = function (appid, userId,limit) {
    var data = {
        "appid": appid,
        "userId": userId,
        "limit": limit,
    }
    // Call rest api using data variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data can be combined in an object which is meaningful, I think it's better to use an object.
And also if you have many parameters, it's better to combined them in an object.
You can for example do something like this :

```
var getMessages = function (credentials,limit) {
    var data = {
        "appid": credentials.appid,
        "userId": credentials.userId,
        "limit": limit,
    }
   ...
}
```